# Can a JS Object's constructor be written in C++ with SpiderMonkey?

Tags: spidermonkey

I would like to implement a constructor for a Javascript Object in C++, using SpiderMonkey 38's API. But a constructor needs access to `this` (the JS Object being constructed) and the docs for `JS::CallArgs` say you mustn't call `thisv()` from a constructor, without suggesting any alternative. Does that mean it isn't actually possible to write a useful constructor in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you just have to create the object that should be returned from the constructor yourself. (Nothing creates an initial object that would be accessible from `this` for your)  Depending on what you need you should look into creating a new JSClass for that object.

```
bool
MyConstructor(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value* vp)
{
  CallArgs args = CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);

  JS::RootedObject obj(cx, JS_NewObject(cx, MyJSClass));
  if (!obj)
    return false;

  args.rval().setObject(*obj);
  return true;
}
```